# Renormalisation scheme dependence of beta function and scale/conformal invariance

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory, perturbation-theory

This question arose when trying to reconcile the way in which the beta function is usually first introduced in the context of perturbative QFT with the statement that a vanishing beta function implies the underlying theory to be conformal. I assume that my confusion is due to my total lack of experience with conformal theories. Let me try to break the question down into three separate parts.

**First:** The statement that a theory with vanishing beta function is conformal. I would appreciate some clarification on whether this statement is logically the correct way around (in the sense of implication) as this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407265/conformal-vs-scale-invariance-of-cal-n-4-supersymmetric-yang-mills-theor) seems to suggest, or if the two statements are even equivalent.

The **second** part of the question concerns in which context the above statement is made. I assume that people are talking about the full, non-perturbative beta function when making this claim, since the perturbative beta function depends on the renormalisation scheme used. This naturally leads to the final (and for me most confusing) part of the question.

**Third:** This concerns the cognitive dissonance I'm having in connecting this to the perturbative notion of the beta function. As an example consider massive $\phi^4$ theory in $d=4$ dimensions,
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi - m^2\phi^2\right) - \frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4 + \mathcal{L}_{\text{ct}},$$
with renormalised parameters $\phi,m,\lambda$. I can evaluate loop corrections using e.g. dim. reg. and perform on-shell renormalisation for the field $\phi$ and the mass $m$. This leads to vanishing anomalous dimensions for both parameters, i.e.
$$\mu\frac{d\phi}{d\mu} = 0,\hspace{1.0cm} \mu\frac{dm^2}{d\mu} = 0.$$
Since the theory does not have any fancy symmetries, the renormalisation condition for the coupling $\lambda$ can be chosen independently (from $\phi,m$) by prescribing the renormalised 4-point function $G_4(s,t,u;\mu,m)$ at given external kinematics ($s=s_0,t=t_0,u=u_0$). Let's choose
$$G_4(s_0,t_0,u_0;\mu,m) \overset{!}{=} - i\lambda,$$
which is just the leading order result, in effect moving all quantum corrections into to the coupling. In this scheme I can show explicitly at one loop that
$$\mu \frac{d\lambda}{d\mu} = 0,$$
but I expect this to hold to any order since the UV-divergences and $\log(\mu)$'s in the bare Green's function, which are all absorbed into the renormalisation factor $Z_\lambda$, should conspire to cancel in the calculation of the anomalous dimension (beta function). Please correct me if this assumption is wrong! Since all anomalous dimensions vanish, the theory is at a fixed point. Yet nothing about the theory is conformal. The fixed point is just an artifact of how we renormalised.

So is there any way to (perturbatively) distinguish a conformal theory from any old theory in an approriately chosen renormalisation scheme? I could imagine that in the perturbative expansion of a true conformal theory it does not matter which scheme I choose, the anomalous dimensions will always vanish. Or am I making the incorrect assumption that conformal theories require perturbative renormalisation in the first place? If there were no UV-divergences, the perturbative beta function would (maybe) be unique. Again, any clarification on my mere speculations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is something wrong with your way of reasoning: the coupling $\lambda$ should certainly be running at one-loop order in the massive $\phi^4$ theory, whatever your choice of renormalization condition.

Comment: Can you point to an argument as to why this should be the case? At one loop I seem to be able to compute $\mu\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}= \epsilon\left[-2\lambda -\frac{3\lambda^2}{16\pi^2}\left(2+\log\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)\right)\right] + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^3) = 0\rvert_{\epsilon=0}$ in the above scheme.

Comment: The logarithm term should not be proportional to $\epsilon$ (as far as I understand you work with dimensional regularization?)

Comment: @M.Jo I think my calculation should be correct. Computing the $\overline{\text{MS}}$ running analogously certainly yields the result known from the literature. I also found that renormalisation schemes in which all anomalous dimensions (incl. the beta function) vanish are not unheard of, see e.g. chapter 7.8 in Collins' book ["Renormalization"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/renormalization/6EA5EEEBB9A02190F7C805856244181B). However, how this relates to conformal theories is still unclear to me.